# Shouldn't the electric dipoles (and thus dielectrics) increase the net electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, dielectric, dipole-moment

We know that the magnetic field is almost always greater in a medium, apart from diamagnetic media, than in vacuum. And the reason is, of course, that the magnetic dipoles align with the external field. Well the exact same thing is true of electric dipoles. But, quite counterintuitively, the net electric field happens to decrease. But how can that be possible?

I mean the far field of a dipole (electric or magnetic) is in the direction of the dipole moment and thus the external field, and yet the electric field in a dielectric is smaller. And occasionally the reason given is that the charges cancel each other in most of the region except the outer ends of a capacitor etc. And so those charges produce an electric field opposing the external field. Well the last statement might be true but at the same time, the charges at the ends ar separated by countless dipole moments. So those should completely overwhelm the effect of already very weak(because of inverse relationship with distance squared) electric field and thus overall contribution of the medium should be in favor of the external electric field. But....

I know that experimentally it's been verified time and again that dielectrics do decrease the net electric field, so there must be some fault in my line of reasoning. And that's what I'm trying to understand. What is the mistake I've made and what's the actual reason that the net electric field is decreased.

Edit: See comment below by knzhou. I understand that ε is suitable for calculating capacitance, but what about electrostatic force? Only far field(for superposition) matters for that.

Comment: The far fields of magnetic and electric dipoles are the same, but the _near_ fields (inside the dipoles themselves) are opposite in direction. That difference in turn can be traced to the fact that in magnetostatics, the electric field only has nonzero divergence, while the magnetic field only has nonzero curl.

Comment: @knzhou Yes i get that. But that's not I'm concerned about. I understand that the electric permittivity serves well for capacitance etc. Because then in calculating the potential difference i have to take the near fields into account while integrating. But what about in electrostatics. I don't need to think about the field in intervening points whatsoever. I only need to use superposition principal to find the force by one particle on the other and so far field is what I'm gonna need to find the superposition. So ε in 1/4πε should be smaller than ε_0